# Tell Gnome 40 to start on the first workspace, rather than Activities

Tags: rhel, gnome, login

I have recently upgraded to Rocky Linux 9, a RHEL derivative, which uses Gnome 40 by default. When I log in I find myself in the Activities view. Is there a way to tell it to start on the fist workspace instead? I run Firefox and Thunderbird automatically and I installed the Dash-to-dock extension that comes with the distribution, so I have seldom any use for the Activities view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Darkblade's answer is likely to be the standard solution, it is not available with the version of `dash-to-dock` that's packaged with RHEL 9 and derivatives. For those there is a `no-overview` extension that has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

The dash-to-dock extention has a setting for that, Show overview on startup [image: Show Overview On Startuo]. To make it start on the first workspace, just enable that.

Comment: The version of dash-to-dock that's packaged with RHEL 9 and derivatives must be either an older or a custom one, and it doesn't have that setting.